# Basic Algebra Question Confusion (Parenthesis or Exponents First)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I had a discussion with my friend about whether we do parenthesis or exponents first. Here's the question:

$$2(5)^2.$$

I say the answers 50 because you do the exponent first.

My friend says the answer is a hundred because you distribute the two first and then the exponent.

Who's right?

Comment: You are right. You could've checked this on a calculator though.

Comment: Well, the convention is PEDMAS right, so you "do the parenthesis first" but your parenthetical expression just evaluates to 5! For your friend to be right you would need $(2\times 5)^2$

Comment: @James I know this is nit-picky, but sense we're discussing notation, you should avoid writing 5! when you don't mean $5 \cdot 4\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$

Comment: @Zach466920 it's tough to add emphasis when doing arithmetic.

Comment: $\mathcal{5}$ should help

Comment: $2=\sqrt{2}^2$ so to move the $2$ inside we would get $2(5)^2=(\sqrt{2}(5))^2=2\cdot 25=50$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $50$, even without parenthesis ($2\times5^2=50$). Since you do the exponent first, then multiplication (and then sum, if it exists).

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hierarchy. Brackets, Exponents.. *, / + - Left to Right and you are right.

Comment: Why not some other hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

Using the order of operation (PEMDAS):

Parentheses first

Exponents (ie Powers and Square Roots, etc.)

Multiplication and Division (left-to-right)

Addition and Subtraction (left-to-right)

You are right the answer is 50.